# How do I remove the strips on the mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I have recently run into a problem where after subdivisions, my mesh will create these horizontal streaks across the object. Is there any way to fix this?

[image: Example:]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your topology creates these stripes:

[image]

To remove them, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide* and choose *Iterations > 4* in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Then cut an orthogonal edge loop with the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally and <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through):

[image]

No more stripes:

[image]